# How is the Lagrangian or the costate variable obtained for optimal control problems?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

I'm new to this topic, I've just reviewed some lectures on the Langrangian. I'm not entirely sure how analagous the costate variables and Lagrangian are, so I may be conflating things?

I see that the [Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(control_theory)) is a function of the costate variables. If I remember from my lecture videos, the Lagrangian is obtained from only the constraint and the function you wish to maximise. I don't see an analagous way to obtain the costate variables.

Answer (score 0):

The costate variables are the Lagrange multipliers. A distinction though, is that for optimal control problems, the costate variables are functions of time.